# Why don't inherit from ifstream

Tags: c++, stream, ifstream, streambuf

I want to create a custom input file stream which automatically strips comments and other garbage data. I came up with the following solution:

```
class FileReader : public std::ifstream
{
public:
  explicit FileReader(const char* fName) { open(fName); }

  ~FileReader() { if (is_open()) close(); }

  template <typename T, bool IsBaseOfSerializable>
  struct DoRead
  {
    void operator()(std::ifstream& ifs, T& data) { ifs >> data; }
  };

  template <typename T>
  struct DoRead<T, true>
  {
    void operator()(FileReader& reader, T& data) { data.Deserialize(reader); }
  };

  template <typename T>
  friend FileReader& operator>>(FileReader& reader, T& data)
  {
    reader.SkipCommentsAndGarbage();
    DoRead<T, std::is_base_of<ISerializable, T>::value> doread;
    doread(reader, data);
    return reader;
  }

  void SkipCommentsAndGarbage() {... }
};
```

I also have interface `ISerializable` containing `Serialize/Deserialize` methods. Everything looks fine with me.

But I have read that I should never inherit from `std::ifstream` and should create custom `std::streambuf`.

Could you please explain why is it bad to inherit from `std::ifstream` and how can I create custom `std::streambuf` which ignores comments and other data in similar way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not clear to me how you expect your class to work.  The
`operator>>` functions are *not* virtual in `std::istream`, and
sooner or later (generally sooner, in well written code), you'll
end up with a `std::istream&`.  You're idea for forwarding can
be used in some cases, but in such cases, you don't inherit from
`std::ifstream`; you contain a pointer to an `istream`, and
forward to it.  (By not inheriting, you ensure that you can't
end up with a `istream&`.  Which is limiting, but acceptable in
certain cases.)

The normal way of doing this is to provide a filtering
streambuf, which filters the input text.  For example, if
comments are from a `#` to the end of the line, and you don't
have to worry about quotes and such, something as simple as the
following will work:

```
class UncommentStreambuf : public std::streambuf
{
    std::streambuf* mySource;
    std::istream*   myOwner;
    char            myBuffer;
protected:
    int underflow() override
    {
        int results = mySource->sbumpc();
        if ( results == '#' ) {
            while ( mySource->sgetc() != '\n' ) {
                mySource->sbumpc();
            }
        }
        if (results != traits_type::eof()) {
            myBuffer = results;
            setg( &myBuffer, &myBuffer, &myBuffer + 1 );
        } else {
            setg( nullptr, nullptr, nullptr );
        }
        return results;
    }
public:
    UncommentStreambuf( std::streambuf* source )
        : mySource( source )
        , myOwner( nullptr )
    {
    }
    UncommentStreambuf( std::istream& source )
        : mySource( source.rdbuf() )
        , myOwner( &source )
    {
        source.rdbuf( this );
    }
    ~UncommentStreambuf()
    {
        if ( myOwner != nullptr ) {
            myOwner->rdbuf( mySource );
        }
    }
};
```

If you need to handle other types of comments, or worry about
quoted comment characters, you'll need more logic (with possibly
a private buffer to collect characters, in order to test for
a sequence of more than one character).

Answer (score 3):

Because publicly inheriting to modify the behavior of `ifstream` will lead to unintended consequences, because it still is an `istream` and will be treated as such in many cases - stripping away your custom behavior:

- When passing `FileReader` to a function that expects an `::std::istream&`, your custom functionality will not be used
- Any class `C` with an operator like `template<typename T> T& operator>>(T& in, C& target);` will be unusable
- Whenever any functionality of the underlying `istream` is used directly, your wrapper functions do not work

In your case, you could simply switch to having your `ifstream` as a member or change its inheritance to private.

Answer (score 1):

It's basically the `std::iostream` design to customise `std::streambuf`, that's where all context specific functionality resides.